# Is wiki vandalism illegal?

Tags: united-states, internet, is-x-legal, spam

Is it legal to vandalize wikis if the vandal doesn't use hacked accounts? Could the vandal either be prosecuted or sued?

Comment: It would depend on what exact conduct you mean when you say "vandalism", and on the terms of use of the particular wiki site.  For instance, [Wikipedia's Terms of Use](https://foundation.wikimedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use/en) does prohibit "vandalism" (though it does not define it) and also "with the intent to deceive, posting content that is false or inaccurate".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems with this kind of vandalism, one of them clearly that the internet is international and vandalism can be performed from everywhere on servers everywhere in the world. And so it may be (both technically and legally) difficult to get hold of the vandal. Therefore, most wikis primarily focus on blocking offending accounts or their IPs and hope that this helps at least for a while. Only if it doesn't and the vandalism continues for extended time periods, legal measures are considered.

Legally speaking though, vandalism is prohibited by many jurisdictions and of course by the terms of use of the wiki operators.

For instance, the [Swiss criminal code](https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/54/757_781_799/en) Art 147 explicitly puts "abusing of data processing equipment" under penalty and hence gives website operators a legal backup for setting up rules for the use of their services.

> Computer fraud
> Art. 147

> 1 Any person who with a view to his own or another's unlawful gain, by the incorrect, incomplete or unauthorised use of data, or in a similar way, influences the electronic or similar processing or transmission of data and as a result causes the transfer of financial assets, thus occasioning loss to another, or immediately thereafter conceals such a transfer shall be liable to a custodial sentence not exceeding five years or to a monetary penalty.

> 2 If the offender acts for commercial gain, he shall be liable to a custodial sentence not exceeding ten years or to a monetary penalty of not less than 90 daily penalty units.

Technically, the law even requires prosecution *ex officio*, even though without a hint from the operator, the police won't start an investigation. I'm sure the US has a similar law. The problem is, as with all internet crimes, it's practical application, particularly because often website operator and offender are not living in the same country.

**Edit**
After reading the exact text again (it was unavailable yesterday) Art 147 is mostly about fraud performed by computers (classical "hacking") but it shouldn't be difficult to argue that fighting and reverting vandalism requires significant (technical and personal) effort and hence the operator looses money. Additionally, there's Art 144<sup>bis</sup> which matches even better for the scenario here:

> Damage to data
> Art. 144bis

> 1. Any person who without authority alters, deletes or renders unusable data that is stored or transmitted electronically or in some other similar way shall be liable on complaint to a custodial sentence not exceeding three years or to a monetary penalty.

> If the offender has caused major damage, a custodial sentence of from one to five years may be imposed. The offence is prosecuted ex officio.

> 2. Any person who manufactures, imports, markets, advertises, offers or otherwise makes accessible programs that he knows or must assume will be used for the purposes described in paragraph 1 above, or provides instructions on the manufacture of such programs shall be liable to a custodial sentence not exceeding three years or to a monetary penalty.

> If the offender acts for commercial gain, a custodial sentence of from one to five years may be imposed.

Comment: This wiki doesn't seem to have any terms of use. The vandal *might* even be able to claim "I didn't know I wasn't supposed to delete vast amounts of content and replace all the pages with 'crap' repeated thousands of times."

Comment: @Someone You are true that the terms and conditions are at least not obvious to find. But "I didn't know" was never a good excuse for breaking a rule or law.

Comment: Wiki's generally have very open availability of editorial rights and have internal structures (like revert functionality) that minimizes the damage caused by "vandalism". So absent something like a denial of service attack, I very much doubt that this would give rise to criminal law consequences.

Comment: @ohwilleke I disagree. I am an active Wikipedia editor and I know how much effort and time it takes to fight vandalism. Even if it is "just" a revert, somebody needs to check the edit and click the revert button. Then he has to report the vandal and an administrator has to click more buttons to block the offender. It's a matter of seconds, maybe minutes, but sums up with the pure amount of bad-faith edits.

Comment: Additional costs arise because the vandalism fighting tools need to be provided (e.g. the feature to block vandals) and because the vandalism-only edits still occupy disk space.

Comment: @PMF All of that is true (I am also an active Wikipedia editor), but I've never seen a Wiki vandalism issue resolved in the criminal justice system ever, on any Wiki and I've never heard of that being done (rarely you see civil cases alleging defamation or fraud via a Wikipedia edit, on behalf of an injured third-party). Most Wikis see vandalism the way hockey sees someone committing a foul or penalty, they deal with the offense in house. Nor have I seen any Wiki v. Vandal lawsuits.

Comment: @ohwilleke That's probably true, I also can't recall or find a case of a trial due to vandalism. But that doesn't mean it wouldn't be possible. And maybe making an example (with a severe penalty) would scare others...

Comment: @PMF Most vandalism type offenses have fair market value sentencing grades. The economic valuation of a single instance of vandalism of a Wiki staffed predominantly by volunteers would be in the petty offense/shoplifting magnitude offense, yet would be as expensive as lots of white collar felonies to prosecute.

Comment: @ohwilleke Sure, but there are some vandals (similar to the one in the comments of the question) that do this over and over again, creating hundreds of sockpuppets over many years. I would like to see a trial against one of those.